# setResultsName shows only first list item

Tags: python, python-2.x, pyparsing

Consider the following minimal example:

```
from pyparsing import Word, delimitedList
the_list = delimitedList(Word("fine").setResultsName("extension", listAllMatches=True))
prefixed = Word("okay").setResultsName("base") + the_list
prefixed.addParseAction(lambda x: map(lambda element: x.base + element, x.extension))
final = prefixed.setResultsName("doesNotWork", listAllMatches=True) + Word("x")

final.parseString("ookf,i,n,ex")
```

returns

```
(['ookf', 'ooki', 'ookn', 'ooke', 'x'], {'doesNotWork': [((['ookf'], {}), 0)]})
```

How can I get pyparsing to assign the whole list, ['ookf', 'ooki', 'ookn', 'ooke', 'x'], to doesNotWork, and not only the first list item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change `prefixed` to:

```
prefixed = Group(Word("okay").setResultsName("base") + the_list)
```

Will this be acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for pyparsing and your reply. Unfortunately I have problems getting my parseAction to work with your suggestion. When I'll try prefixed.parseString.("okf,i,n,e")base, I'll get an empty string, rather than "ok"

Comment: The Group adds another layer of nesting of the results - try `prefixed.parseString('...')[0].base`.